# MySQL cumulative sum grouped by date but exclude after certain date

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a query involving dates that is really close to being complete, but I can't quite get the last part. The table columns are:

```
purchased TINYINT
purchased_date DATE
expired TINYINT
expiration_date DATE
```

The query I'm running is this:

```
SELECT 
    e_date,
    num_interactions,
    @runningTotal := @runningTotal + totals.num_interactions AS runningTotal
FROM
(SELECT 
    DATE(purchase_date) AS e_date,
    COUNT(*) AS num_interactions
FROM domain_names AS d
WHERE purchased = 1
AND purchase_date != "0000-00-00"
GROUP BY DATE(d.purchase_date)) totals
ORDER BY e_date;
```

It works well, but I need one final adjustment. I need to exclude/subtract the names from the running total that were expired (based on `expiration date`) after the `e_date`.

In other words, if the running total shouldn't count a domain after the date it has expired. Thank you so much for any advice here. This is my first post here, so hopefully I've explained it clearly.

EDIT:
I've put together an MCRE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domain_names` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchased` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `purchase_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expired` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_domain_names_on_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `domain_names` (`id`, `name`, `purchased`, `purchase_date`, `expired`, `expiration_date`) VALUES
  ('1', 'example1.com', '1', '2019-01-12', NULL, '2019-08-12'),
  ('2', 'example2.com', '1', '2019-01-12', NULL, '2020-10-12'),
  ('3', 'example3.com', '1', '2019-01-12', '1', '2019-10-12'),
  ('4', 'example4.com', '1', '2019-10-12', NULL, '2020-10-12'),
  ('5', 'example2.com', '1', '2019-03-19', NULL, '2020-03-19'),
  ('6', 'example3.com', '1', '2019-08-19', NULL, '2020-08-10'),
  ('7', 'example4.com', '1', '2019-11-28', NULL, '2020-10-12');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d9f71/1/1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for the info @Strawberry. I've put together an MCRE here as requested: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d9f71/1/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d9f71/1/1)

Comment: Can you post the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach not relying on variables and subqueries

```sql
SELECT 
    DATE(d.purchase_date),
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.id) AS num_interactions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS cumulative_sum_not_expired
FROM domain_names AS d
LEFT JOIN domain_names AS c ON (DATE(c.purchase_date) <= DATE(d.purchase_date)
                                AND c.purchased = 1
                                AND c.purchase_date != 0
                                AND c.expiration_date >= CURDATE())
WHERE d.purchased = 1
      AND d.purchase_date != 0
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d9f71/36/0

You can adjust the exclusion here :
`c.expiration_date >= CURDATE()`

Comment: Thank you very much @zimza. This worked perfectly! I made a small change by adding `OR c.expiration_date is null` to account for rows that don't have an expiration date. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

if you need exclude expired domains, then you should add where clause `expiration_date > CURDATE()` to couning subquery or count only not expired domains `COUNT(case when expiration_date > CURDATE() then 1 end)`...

```
SET @runningTotal := 0;
SET @runningTotalNE := 0;
SELECT 
    e_date,
    num_interactions,
    @runningTotal := @runningTotal + totals.num_interactions AS runningTotal,
    @runningTotalNE := @runningTotalNE + totals.notexpired AS runningTotalNotExpired
FROM
    (SELECT 
     purchase_date AS e_date,
     COUNT(*) AS num_interactions,
     COUNT(case when expiration_date > CURDATE() then 1 end) AS notexpired
     FROM domain_names AS d
     WHERE purchased = 1
     /*AND expiration_date > CURDATE()*/
     AND purchase_date != "0000-00-00"
     GROUP BY d.purchase_date) totals
     ORDER BY e_date
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @AdamSilenko. What I meant was that row in the running total, only count domains that were not expired on that `e_date`.